# Abnormal behaviour of Visual Studio and Blend

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

i get a strange trouble ,i am developing a software (WPF) with Expression Blend 4 and Visual Studio 10 and untill yesterday i could modify my code in Xaml but today after open the project to continue to work i tried to add some new UIElement as Grid,Border,Textbox and so on  i could save without trouble but when i launch the software to verify the result those UIElemen added before did not appear ,i checked out well if the Visibility are Visible and the opacity is nto set to the value =0 ,so i tried to repeat to add others UIElemtn in others Window of the same project but this strange behaviour continuing to bother me...

Do you have any idea what it can be or have some advice to help and work out this step??

Thanks so much for your attention,

Cheers

Comment: Sounds like something that can occur if you're jumping between Blend and VS often. Make sure you're saving to the correct thing and paying attention to what you're doing between them as new changes updated between the two. By chance could this be the case? Actively switching between Blend & VS often?

Comment: @ Chris W ,i tried to use the project with only Blend or Vs but it repeat the same error .Thanks so much man

Comment: Oh, I figured maybe some changes weren't being saved between switching. So the behavior is, you make some changes, you run it, changes disappear and aren't showing at runtime? You're Ctrl+Shift+S'ing as you go?

Comment: woaah ,it is really strange ,there is someone that met this issue in past time 'cos i can not work on that project anymore ,everything i save after did not appear anymore on the project...